# Capistrano and Git. How to update production but don't delete some files?

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano

On every deploy:update production server lost files, that not in git repository, such as user files, cache etc.

:deploy_via set to :remote_cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solved this problem by moving files to other direcory (system/shared) and create a symlink to it.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail?

Comment: Imagine that in normal situation your upload files stores in public/uploads folder. But in capistrano, every deploy deletes all app folder and take files from git repo. But repo, of course, doesn't store upload files. Capistrano created system/shared folder which never cleaned. Solution is create symlink: `ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public` every deploy.